# How to update widget TextView from running service?

Tags: android, widget, textview

I have a running service which is getting some data, and as the new data comes I want my widget's textview to show it. How can I update it?

Answer (score 1):

You can send out a broadcast from the service. Register the broadcast receiver for you app widget to also receive those broadcasts. On those broadcasts you can update the widget as well.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I don't have any Activities in my app. There's just a widget without config Activity, and my Service which can by started by pressing the button on widget.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize you meant AppWidget. I've edited my answer.